# How to include figure or table with number in the title of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm looking for a way to integrate automatically the Table x or Figure Y in the title of a tcolorbox.

Any idea ?

Comment: what do you mean by "integrate automatically"? In other words, what kind of integration and automation are you looking forward to? I think you can be a little more verbose here?

Comment: Numbering + title...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility, defining two environments with the appropriate settings: the first one, giving the title `Table <number>` and the other one, `Figure <number>`; each environment has a mandatory argument to add some caption-like text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{tctable}[1]
{\stepcounter{table}%
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=\tablename~\thetable: #1}
\begin{tcolorbox}}
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\newenvironment{tcfigure}[1]
{\stepcounter{figure}%
\tcbset{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title=\figurename~\thefigure: #1}
\begin{tcolorbox}}
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tctable}{test table}
This is a table \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tctable}

\begin{tcfigure}{test figure}
This is a figure \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcfigure}

\begin{tctable}{another test table}
This is another table \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tctable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how to give a name after Table X or Figure Y ?

Comment: @s__C please see my updated answer.

Comment: Fine. Now how to adjust the size to the content ? Other than specifying a width each time.

Comment: @s__C Since this new requirement is not directly related to the original question,  I think it is better to ask a fresh new question.

Comment: OK. I can manage without it with simply specifying the width of tcolorbox.